# Running bluetooth on Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: pi-4, bluetooth

I hope this is the correct group for this question. If not I can redirect the post.

I have developped a BSP for Raspberry Pi 4 2G using Buildroot.

I enabled the rpi-bt-firmware, rpi-firmware and the bluez5 utils and tools, but running the bluetooth is failing.

What I have tried for the moment :

The bluetoothctl command : permits to enter the bluetooth mode

In the bluetooth mode, I try to display the controllers available with the command list but none is displayed:

```
    #bluetoothctl
    Agent registered
    [bluetooth]# list
    [bluetooth]#
```

It is confirmed by running the command scan (used to detect available bluetooth devices around) which returns :

```
[bluetooth]# scan on
No default controller available
[bluetooth]#
```

I also try the rfkill list command to display all available wireless controllers and it returns a Wireless LAN but no bluetooth

```
# rfkill list
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
         Soft blocked: no
         Hard blocked: no
#
```

I searched in the buildroot configuration and in the prompt help it is mentioned that the rpi-bt-firmware package is used for ras pi 3b. Is there another package for ras pi4? I wonder if all firmwares were gathered in rpi-firmware. I installed it but the result is still the same as above : no bluetooth.

Any help or link will be much appreciated. I can provide any extra info needed.

Comment: The `bluetoothctl` tool requires that D-Bus is up and running to communicate with `bluetoothd` the Bluetooth daemon. I don't know if it is that one or both of them has not been started. You could try using `sudo btmgmt info` to see if that can find the Bluetooth controller as that  uses a user socket (rather than D-Bus) to communicate with `bluetoothd`. The `hci*` set of tools have been deprecated but they are still on RPi so you could try `hciconfig` to see if that finds the Bluetooth controller as that does not go through `bluetoothd`

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I tried `sudo btmgmt info` but the command is not available in my system (perhaps beacause as an embeeded system, it has limited functionnality). I digged into the D-BUS and `bluetoothd` and found out the command `/usr/libexec/bluetooth/bluetoothd&` which outputs **D-BUS setup failed:Name already in use**. I also found out the command `/etc/init.d/S40bluetooth start` which outputs **starting bluetoothd : FAIL!**. As I suspected that bluetoothd was already in use, I tried  `/etc/init.d/S40bluetooth restart` and got **stopping bluetoothd : OK** & **starting bluetoothd :OK**

Comment: After restarting bluetoothd, I tried `hciconfig -a ` which outputs nothing and `rfkill list` which still outputs a wireless LAN but no bluetooth. Finally, I also tried `/etc/init.d/S30dbus restart` which outputs **stopping system message bus: done, starting system message bus: done ** and **[1]* Done     /usr/libexec/bluetooth/bluetoothd**. I coninue digging, any extra help will be appreciated ;)

Comment: If `hciconfig` doesn't output anything then I think there is a fundamental problem. There are various discussions about bluetooth.service not starting successfully on https://github.com/RPi-Distro/pi-bluetooth. Is there anything in the follow that helps you for example? https://github.com/RPi-Distro/pi-bluetooth/pull/22